# visual studio C++ not updating headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, header-files

I'm using visual studio 2013 to program a project in c++ where various structs are held in a header file. Some of the structs contain some static const fields.

For most of the project, everything has been working fine; but recently the compiler stopped recognising new values for the constants. IntelliSense will say that the constants have the new value, but when I debug it shows that those are not the values being used.

Notes: If I delete the line `#include<GameHeaders.h>` at the top then rewrite it again, it uses the new values. I'm also not using precompiled headers.

Comment: Yes, rebuild works. Does that mean I need to rebuild the solution every time I change the header? If there's any way to set Visual Studio to recognise the change and update on an ordinary build, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.  You say the compiler stopped recognizing new values for the constants, and then you say the debugger shows that the new values are not used.  How did you run the debugger on code that the compiler couldn't compile?

Comment: Stopped recognising as in constants already used in the program used the values they had before rather than the latest values - compiling wasn't blocked